# How to make an object out of another object

Tags: java, line, point, graphing

Basically I am trying to make an `endPosition` take the values from position and add to those `x, y` values.

I am just struggling to figure out the right syntax to do so.

```java
Point position= new Point((int) (Math.random()*(max - min)), (int) (Math.random() *(max - min)));
Point endPosition = new Point();
Point endPosition = (position.x + 2);
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply create a new object and pass the required arguments in the constructor.

```
Point position= new Point((int) (Math.random()*(max - min)),(int) (Math.random() *(max - min)));
Point endPosition = new Point(position.x+2, position.y+3);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what i was originally attempting and it wasnt working so i thought there was something wrong with it. Turns out i was just being really dumb and naming new Point endPosition on 2 seperate lines, confusing the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to add `(int) (Math.random()*(max - min)` and `(int) (Math.random() *(max - min)`

You can create 2 data member in the class say `int x` and `int y` and a third data member say `int sum`

and do the following

```
class Point{
int x;
int y;
int sum;
Point(int x,int y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
   }
}
```

And then in main Simply create an instance of the class.

```
Point position = new Point((int) (Math.random()*(max - min)),(int) (Math.random() *(max - min)));

position.sum = position.x+position.y;
```